# Template integrate in asp .net 6

Tags: asp.net-core, templates

I want to integrate a bootswatch theme in my ASP .NET MVC Core project. I am working with Dot net version 6. I can not integrate the template, the background always remains the same in my application. Can anyone suggest to me a proper way to integrate the template?

Answer (score -1):

**1. You can run `npm init --yes`, and install bootswatch with npm command.**

**2. Copy the `node_modules` folder, and paste into the wwwroot.**

*Please include the `node_modules` folder in your project.*

**3. Modify the `_Layout.cshtml`.**

---

#### Test Result

[image]

[image]

For more details, you also can [follow this video to learn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypMHTnXAf_I).

*Tips:* The name in package.json can't same as `bootswatch`, otherwise you will fail to install bootswatch.