# Use npm in Asp .Net Core 6 MVC project (instead of CDNs)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to use npm inside .Net core 6 MVC project. I have added the file `webpack.config.js` as following:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "babel-polyfill",
        "./src/main"
    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: "/js/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/wwwroot/js/"),
        filename: "main.build.js"
    }
};
```

In addition to the files `package.json` and `package-lock.json` those been generated automatically when running `npm init` and installing some libraries.
However, in my HTML I have referred to the file `main.build.js` as following:
`<script src="~/js/main.build.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>`
In my `program.cs` I have already added:
`app.UseDefaultFiles();`
`app.UseStaticFiles();`

**The problems I'm facing are the following:**

- In `main.build.js` on `let Web3 = require('web3');` I'm getting the error `require is not defined`
- I'm converting `require` statement to `import Web3 from "web3"`, I'm getting the error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.
- I'm inserting `type="module"` in `<script src="~/js/main.build.js" type="module" asp-append-version="true"></script>` then I'm getting the error `Failed to resolve module specifier "web3". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`.
- Thus I'm trying to navigate to the accurate relative path by starting with `../../node_modules/` as `import Web3 from "../../node_modules/web3";` so I'm getting the error `GET https://localhost:7101/node_modules/web3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404`
- I need, in addition, to use npm packages in several js files, not only inside `main.build.js`, so what else should be done inside `webpack.config.js`?

**Any hints, tutorials, help, or recommendation will be appreciated. I would love also to see a GitHub code example where npm is used inside .Net Core 6 MVC project.**

My project structure is as following:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tested integrating bootswatch in asp.net 6 project and everything worked fine. [You can check my test result.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71044979/7687666)

Compared to the screenshot you provided so far, you are missing the node_modules folder under wwwroot.

For more details, you can [refer to the youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypMHTnXAf_I) I provided.